# ORDER A TABLE BY TWO COLUMNS

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Hi Everybody,

```
       I have a table which contains two type of Establishments:
```

If the SIRET IS NULL --> IT is an ENTREPRISE

IF the SIRET IS NOT NULL --> It is an etablishement

In My table, I have always this condiction: if SIRET is NULL that means SIREN is NOT NULL.

What I want is to display the SIRET and SIREN in the same COLUMNS and order the table by company name and (SIRET IF NOT NULL) Or ( SIREN if Not NULL)

This is my query:

```
          select  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_RCE_ID, 
          CUSTOMER.COMM_REGNUM_CUST,CUSTOMER.GROUP_CODE, 
          CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CORPORATE_NAME, 
          Replace(CUSTOMER.ADDRESS_COMPANY, '|', ', ') as ADDRESS_COMPANY, 
          CUSTOMER.COUNTRY_CODE, CUSTOMER.POST_CODE, CUSTOMER.CITY, 
          CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE1,CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE2, 
          CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE3, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE4, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE5, CUSTOMER.CREATED_DATE, 
          CUSTOMER.CREATED_BY,CUSTOMER.UPDATED_DATE, CUSTOMER.UPDATED_BY, CUSTOMER.TENANT_ID, 
          CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT, CUSTOMER.VAT_INTRA, CUSTOMER.VAT_SETTLEMENT,CUSTOMER.IS_HEADQUARTERS, 
          CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_SAP_ID, CUSTOMER.ADDRESSGUID, CUSTOMER.SIREN_CORP as SIREN, CUSTOMER.COMMERCIAL_SEGMENT, CUSTOMER.CODE_NAF, 
          CUSTOMER.JUR_STATUS_COMP, CUSTOMER.SHARE_CAP_AMT,CUSTOMER.IS_ACTIVE_RCE, CUSTOMER.REGISTRATION_PLACE,STATUS.STATUS_NAME , 
          CUSTOMER.RCE_ETAB_ID, REPLACE (CUSTOMER.COMM_REGNUM_CUST,' ','') AS SIRET  from CUSTOMER


          join CUSTOMER_STATUS on CUSTOMER_STATUS.CUSTOMER_STATUS_ID = ( 
          select * from (select CUSTOMER_STATUS_ID from CUSTOMER_STATUS 
          where CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_STATUS.CUSTOMER_ID order by CUSTOMER_STATUS.UPDATED_DATE desc)  CUSTOMER_STATUS where rownum = 1 )


          join STATUS on CUSTOMER_STATUS.STATUS_ID = STATUS.STATUS_ID
```

How can I order by CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CORPORATE_NAME(COMPANY OR ESTABLISHEMENT NAME) and another column (SIRET OR SIRET ASSUMING IF ONE IS NULL THE OTHER IS NOT) and Put the SIRET AND SIREN IN THE SAME COLUMN RESULT

Thans you in advance.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: You would be well served if you tried a simpler example code, just the parts you need to ask about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial solution might be

```
SELECT 
        .
        .
        .
       customer.customer_corporate_name, 
       isnull(customer.siren_corp
              ,Replace(customer.comm_regnum_cust, ' ', '')) AS SiretSiren
        .
        .
        .
FROM   customer 
       JOIN customer_status 
        .
        .
        .
         ON customer_status.status_id = status.status_id 
ORDER by customer.customer_corporate_name,SiretSiren
```